# Bind() Failed on Ubuntu, What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, sockets, bind

I downloaded a C++ program from Github which does Bandwidth estimation using Pair to pair algorithm. I've compiled and installed the program on my system but when I initialize the Bind() function to bind to port 53 for e.g, it says either Bind() failed, or an infinite "Waiting for Client". I'm not very experienced with socket programming and using BIND. Are there some rules in play?

Here is the program source if needed:
https://github.com/npbendre/Bandwidth-Estimation-using-Packet-Pair-Probing-Algorithm

```
/********************************************************
*  Program: Bandwidth Estimation            *
*                           *
*  Summary:                     *
*   This file contains the server code      *
*                           *
*********************************************************/

#include "defs.h"

int quit = 0;   /* CNT-C exit flag */

#define RESET 0
#define HEX 16
#define MSZ_BEGIN 5
#define SEQ_BEGIN 5
#define BSZ_BEGIN 9
#define MAX_WAIT 30
#define HEADER_SIZE 28

#define TO_Mbits(x) (x*8/1048576)

struct Client {
    int cmd;
    char sessionID[ID_LEN+1];
    unsigned int msgSize;
    unsigned int seq;
    unsigned int burstSize;
    unsigned int burstCnt;
    unsigned int numRecv;
    double bandwidth;
};

/* SIGINT handler */
void CNT_C_Code() 
{ 
    printf("CNT-C Interrupt, exiting...\n");
    quit = 1; 
}

/* SIGALRM handler */
void alarmHandler() { } 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sock;               /* Socket */
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;      /* Local address */
    struct sockaddr_in clientAddr;      /* Client address */
    struct sockaddr_in dupClAddr;       /* Temporary address */
    unsigned int addrLen;           /* Client address length */
    unsigned int serverPort;        /* Local port */
    struct sigaction sa_int;        /* For SIGINT */
    struct sigaction sa_alrm;       /* For SIGALRM */
    int cmd = RESET;            /* Server commands */
    char buffer[MIN_MSG_LEN];       /* Receive buffer */
    char results[RESULT_LEN];       /* Results buffer */
    char *msg = NULL;           /* Client message */
    struct Client cl;           /* Current client */
    int recvlen;                /* Received message length */
    int seq;                /* Sequence number */
    struct timespec ts1;            /* time structure */
    struct timespec ts2;            /* time structure */
    struct timespec *ts = NULL;     /* Switch pointer */
    int swtch = 0;              /* Switch flag for timespecs */
    int cnt = 0;
    char temp[ID_LEN+1];


    /* Invalid invocation of the program */
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Syntax: %s <port number>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    serverPort = atoi(argv[1]);

    /* create datagram socket */
    if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0)
        DieWithError("socket() failed");

    /* build local address struct */
    memset(&serverAddr, 0, sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(serverPort);

    /* bind to local address */
    printf("Server: binding to port %d\n", serverPort);
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) < 0) {
        close(sock);
        DieWithError("bind() failed");
    }

    /* assign handler and initialize set to all signals */
    sa_int.sa_handler = CNT_C_Code;
    sa_alrm.sa_handler = alarmHandler;  
    if (sigfillset(&sa_int.sa_mask) < 0 || sigfillset(&sa_alrm.sa_mask) < 0) {
            close(sock);
        DieWithError("sigfillset() failed");
    }

    /* set the handler */
    sa_int.sa_flags = sa_alrm.sa_flags = 0;
        if (sigaction(SIGINT, &sa_int, 0) < 0 || sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa_alrm, 0) < 0) {
            close(sock);
        DieWithError("sigaction() failed");
    }

    addrLen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    /* Run until CNT-C */
    for ( ; !quit; ) {

        if (cmd == RESET) {
            /* reset session id */
            memset(&cl, 0, sizeof(cl));
            errno = swtch = cnt = 0;
            ts = &ts1;

            printf("Waiting for Client...\n");

            /* get the first message from client */
            recvfrom(sock, buffer, MIN_MSG_LEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddr, &addrLen);

            if (errno == EINTR) continue;

            memcpy(&dupClAddr, &clientAddr, addrLen);
            cl.cmd = buffer[0]-'0';     /* get the client command */
        }

        /* Received START_MSG, send START_ACK */
        if (cl.cmd == START_MSG) {

            getFromMsg(cl.sessionID, buffer, SID_BEGIN, ID_LEN);    /* retrieve session ID */

            getFromMsg(temp, buffer, MSZ_BEGIN, ID_LEN);        /* retrieve message size */
            cl.msgSize = strtol(temp, NULL, HEX);

            getFromMsg(temp, buffer, BSZ_BEGIN, ID_LEN);        /* retrieve burst size */
            cl.burstSize = strtol(temp, NULL, HEX);

            if (!msg) msg = (char *) calloc(cl.msgSize+1, sizeof(char));

            printf("\n");
            printf("Serving client with session ID: %s\n", cl.sessionID);

            /* set sending buffer to START_ACK */
            cmd = START_ACK;
            *msg = cmd + '0';
            strcpy(msg+SID_BEGIN, cl.sessionID);

            /* send START_ACK to client */
            printf("=== Received START_MSG, sending START_ACK...\n");
            sendto(sock, msg, strlen(msg)+1, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddr, addrLen);
        }

        if (cmd == START_ACK) {
            int once = 1;

            /* accept client bursts */          
            for ( ; ; ) {

                alarm(MAX_WAIT);    /* wait till client sends next message, used when client crashes */

                recvlen = recvfrom(sock, msg, cl.msgSize+1, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &dupClAddr, &addrLen);
                clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, ts);      /* get time */

                if (errno == EINTR) {
                    if (!quit) {
                        free(msg);
                        msg = NULL;
                        cl.cmd = cmd = RESET;
                        printf("Server Timeout: Resetting...\n\n");
                    }
                    break;
                }
                alarm(0);

                if (recvlen != cl.msgSize+1)        /* damaged packet */
                    continue;

                /* wrong client */
                if (memcmp(&dupClAddr, &clientAddr, addrLen) || strncmp(cl.sessionID, msg+SID_BEGIN, ID_LEN))
                    break;

                if ((cl.cmd = *msg-'0') == START_MSG)       /* client did not receive START_ACK */
                    break;

                if (cl.cmd == DONE) {               /* Client done bursting */
                    cmd = RESULTS_MSG;
                    break;
                }

                ++cl.numRecv;
                ts = ((swtch = 1-swtch)) ? &ts2 : &ts1;     /* switch time pointer */

                getFromMsg(temp, msg, SEQ_BEGIN, ID_LEN);   /* get sequence number */
                seq = strtol(temp, NULL, HEX);

                /* change in sequence */
                if (seq != cl.seq) {

                    once = 1;
                    cl.seq = seq;
                    ts = &ts1;
                    swtch = 0;
                    ++cl.burstCnt;

                    printf("=== Receiving from burst #%d...\n", cl.seq);
                }
                else {
                    /* get time interval only if its from the same burst sequence */
                    if (once) { 
                        once = 0;
                        continue;
                    }

                    /* calculate average bandwidth */
                    cl.bandwidth *= cnt++;
                    cl.bandwidth += ((double) cl.msgSize+1+HEADER_SIZE) / 
                            ((swtch) ? getTimeDiff(ts1, ts2) : getTimeDiff(ts2, ts1));
                    cl.bandwidth /= (double) cnt;
                }

                /* not retrieving data from message */
            }
        }

        if (cmd == RESULTS_MSG) {
            float totExpected = cl.burstSize * cl.burstCnt;

            /* create results */
            results[0] = cmd + '0';
            sprintf(results+SID_BEGIN, "%s:%f:%.2f:%u:%u", cl.sessionID, TO_Mbits(cl.bandwidth),
                    ((totExpected-cl.numRecv)/totExpected)*100, cl.numRecv, cl.burstCnt);

            printf("\n");
            printf("=== Received DONE, sending RESULTS_MSG...\n");
            sendto(sock, results, RESULT_LEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &dupClAddr, addrLen);

            alarm(MAX_WAIT);
            recvfrom(sock, msg, cl.msgSize+1, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &dupClAddr, &addrLen);

            if (errno == EINTR) {
                if (!quit) {
                    free(msg);
                    msg = NULL;
                    cmd = RESET;
                    printf("Server Timeout: Resetting...\n\n");
                }
                continue;
            }
            alarm(0);

            /* wrong client */
            if (memcmp(&dupClAddr, &clientAddr, addrLen) || strncmp(cl.sessionID, msg+SID_BEGIN, ID_LEN))   
                continue;

            if (*msg-'0' == DONE)           /* client did not receive RESULTS_MSG */
                 continue;

            if (*msg-'0' == DONE_ACK) {     /* received DONE_ACK from client */

                printf("=== Received DONE_ACK.\n\n");

                free(msg);
                msg = NULL;
                cmd = RESET;
            }
        }
    }

    if (msg) free(msg);
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include the source code in the question itself. Also check `errno` after bind fails to see what the actual error is.

Comment: Yes sorry, I have included the source code. Also the errno command doesn't print any resulting errors.

Comment: `errno` isn't a command, it's a variable, accessible after doing `#include <errno.h>`.

Comment: Actually I noticed thanks to Konrad that I had to run the ./client executable after the ./server is waiting in order for it to work. I'll include the errno header and see.

Answer (score 1):

Try port number greater than 1024 - maybe OS is blocking binding on lower number ports for non-privileged applications.

Comment: I tried other ports like 8080 and 1025, its just stuck at "Waiting for Client". I will include the source code now in the question.

Comment: Ok, but have you run any client? recv method is blocking - it waits for input

Comment: Run a client how? I thought I could just run ./server 8080 and it will bind to it. How would I make a client to accept it?

Comment: In code you linked to there's client.c. Server runs probably properly - it states that it'll wait for client and it waits for incoming connections.

Comment: Okay I noticed that, I'll go ahead and run the ./client executable and try to make them communicate. I'll post updates if I run into trouble, thank you for your time.